# cannot cancel touchID on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, debugging, fingerprint

A quick question.

I have implemented touchID in a little hobby project, just to try it out.

but after writing code like

```
    LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
    context.localizedFallbackTitle = @"";
    NSError   *error;
    BOOL success = [context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error];

    if (success) {
         [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics localizedReason:NSLocalizedString(@"Unlock account", nil) reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

            if (error.code == LAErrorUserCancel) {
                NSLog(@"Canceled");
             }
         }];
     }
```

The touchID success works. But I don't seem to be able to hit the cancel button to remove the alert/popup window.

Thanks!

Btw I have iOS 8.1.3
(I know this all works on a iPhone 5s iOS 8.2)

**ADDED: I have compared a bit more between the iPhone and the iPad app now and it seems the Cancel button does not even get a touch at all on the iPad.
I have a very striped off app with just a `UIViewController` a `UIButton` and an `UIView`. So my thought is that it is a Apple bug but I want to confirm if anyone else has got this issue and if I should address this directly to Apple.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So! If any one else come upon this problem. Simply do an update of the iOS and/or restart the iPad. Hopefully this will help you as well.
(I actually tried the Apples sample app for TouchID so its a certain that the actual implementation was not the issue.) Damn, I was thiiis close to file my first bugreport to Apple!! :-P